# Anonymous subclasses with extra methods -- scala2 vs. scala3

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, refinement-type

The following code works as (I) expect in scala2 but generates a compile-time error in scala3.  I tried to find an explanation in *Programming in Scala, Fifth Edition* and the web but failed.  Any insights?

```scala
object Main {
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

        val foo = new Foo(7)
        println(foo.double)             // 14

        val bar = new Foo(8) {
            def triple:Int = this.i * 3
        }

        println(bar.double)             // 16
        println(bar.triple)             // 24 in scala2; compile error in scala3
    }
}

class Foo(val i:Int) {
    def double:Int = i*2
}
```

Compilation error:

```
-- [E008] Not Found Error: /tmp/example.scala:12:20 ----
12 |        println(bar.triple)
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                value triple is not a member of Foo
```

Comment: My two cents, this kind of code is hard to read and maintain, also this functionality implied reflection in **Scala 2** _(and that alone has a bunch of implications)_.

Comment: Your question — _any_ question about a compile-time error – should include the full text of the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about error messages, @Seth

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about error messages, Seth, and to Andrey for including it.  As for Luis' comment about being hard to read and maintain -- yup.  I didn't write it; just trying to migrate it with the least disruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your code with `scala -Xprint:typer` , you'll see that `val bar` now explicitly has type `Foo` in Scala 3:

```scala
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
      {
        val foo: Foo = new Foo(7)
        println(foo.double)
        val bar: Foo = 
          {
            final class $anon() extends Foo(8) {
              def triple: Int = this.i.*(3)
            }
            new $anon():Foo
          }
        println(bar.double)
        println(bar.triple)
      }
```

Contrast this to Scala 2, where `bar` gets the refinement type `Foo { def triple: Int }`:

```
      val bar: Foo{def triple: Int} = {
        final class $anon extends Foo {
          def <init>(): <$anon: Foo> = {
            $anon.super.<init>(8);
            ()
          };
          def triple: Int = this.i.*(3)
        };
        new $anon()
      };
```

So, it's

```
val bar: Foo                   // In Scala 3
val bar: Foo{def triple: Int}  // In Scala 2
```

To achieve the behavior of Scala 2, you could introduce a new class `Bar` explicitly:

```
        class Bar extends Foo(8) {
          def triple: Int = this.i * 3
        }
        val bar = new Bar
```

Full compilable code:

```
object Main {
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

        val foo = new Foo(7)
        println(foo.double)             // 14

        class Bar extends Foo(8) {
          def triple: Int = this.i * 3
        }
        val bar = new Bar

        println(bar.double)             // 16
        println(bar.triple)             // 24 in scala2; compile error in scala3
    }
}

class Foo(val i:Int) {
    def double:Int = i*2
}
```

As for the reason why it's inferring `Foo` instead of `Foo { def triple: Int }` - I'm not exactly sure, I guess they just figured out eventually that this behavior plays better with other language features.

How would you explain that `val x = "hello"` infers `x: String` and not `x: "hello"`?

Comment: Well, actually `val x = 1` does infer `x: 1` not sure if with strings it does the same. IIRC, the reason this was changed is because the access of `triple` required reflection and they wanted to make that more explicit. Also, I think there is a `Selectable` trait or something that they could mix to get the **Scala 2** behaviour.

Comment: I cannot entirely exclude the possibility that under some circumstances it would infer `val x: 1 = 1`, but the default behavior that I'm observing is that `val x = 1` is typed as `val x: Int = 1`.

Comment: Ah it seems it has to be a `object` level `final val` for it to infer `1`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/inline.html#inline-constants

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the Scala 3 migration guide at https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-type-inference.html#reflective-type:

> Scala 2 reflective calls are dropped and replaced by the broader Programmatic Structural Types.